# How to retain the Active Tab in Bootstrap 4 after postback or page refresh on ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, postback, page-refresh

I want to to retain the currently active tab after a postback or page refresh (e.g., via <kbd>F5</kbd>) on Bootstrap 4 when using ASP.NET. I have tried many alternatives, but none are working successfully.

Here is the code:

```
<nav>
  <div class="nav nav-tabs" id="nav-tab" role="tablist">
    <a class="nav-item nav-link active" id="nav-home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-home" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-home" aria-selected="true">Home</a>
    <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-profile" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-profile" aria-selected="false">Profile</a>
    <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-contact-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-contact" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-contact" aria-selected="false">Contact</a>
  </div>
</nav>
<div class="tab-content" id="nav-tabContent">
  <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="nav-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-home-tab">...</div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-profile-tab">...</div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-contact" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-contact-tab">...</div>
</div>
```

Comment: The solution for handling this on postback to ASP.NET and on page refresh may be different. What approaches have you tried so far? What version of ASP.NET are you working with? Are you using ASP.NET to generate the current tabs? If so, it may be useful to include that code. Typically, though, this would be handled via the fragment identifier (e.g., `#nav-profile`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after postback/refresh try to set style for the active tab as 
'nav-item nav-link active" using C#

When you click any tab. save its id in c#, after postback, set the same id with class as "nav-item nav-link active"

Comment: hi can you give any example?